# Server Apache shutting down, nothing useful in the /var/log/apache2/error.log

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

My web server on my VPS running on Ubuntu 16.04 suddenly gets down randomly. I have changed nothing that I know of that could cause that behaviour.

I am running an Apache webserver, I use letsencrypt for SSL certificate, sslh to be able to ssh on the port 443 while hosting a web service.

I am not very friendly with system administration and serve maintenance, and so I have no idea where to look at to discover what causes this.

Here is the apache log:

```
[Sun Apr 01 12:54:01.253759 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21594] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Apr 01 12:54:01.253898 2018] [core:notice] [pid 21594] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Apr 01 12:54:01.389638 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21594] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

$ apachectl -t
Syntax OK

$ sudo apache2 -X -f /etc/apache2/apache2.conf 
[Mon Apr 02 11:18:25.990636 2018] [core:warn] [pid 30695] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} is not defined
[Mon Apr 02 11:18:25.990930 2018] [core:warn] [pid 30695] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined
[Mon Apr 02 11:18:25.991090 2018] [core:warn] [pid 30695] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined
[Mon Apr 02 11:18:25.991225 2018] [core:warn] [pid 30695] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined
[Mon Apr 02 11:18:25.991383 2018] [core:warn] [pid 30695] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Mon Apr 02 11:18:26.010130 2018] [core:warn] [pid 30695] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined
[Mon Apr 02 11:18:26.010822 2018] [core:warn] [pid 30695] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
AH00526: Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}
```

I can provide all the log you wish if you are willing to help me. I just don't know what could be useful...

If anyone was kind enough to give me direction, I would be very very grateful.

Comment: Try running `sudo apachectl -t` to do a config check. You can also try manually starting it using `sudo apache2 -X -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf` (you may have to alter the path a bit). To clarify, does apache run fine up until a certain point and then die? SigTerm means something is sending a terminate signal to the process.

Comment: Ok, I added the results. Is there a way to detect the program originating the SigTerm when it happens? I wonder if the whole system is not rebooting actually. How can I know?

Answer (score 2):

You have a **configuration** that **depends on the load of lots of variables** from another file, this file is usually called "**envvars**".

By **loading apache2 directly without loading envvars in your environment you will get the errors** you do.

Note the **syntax** check is **OK** when you use "**apachectl**" but not when you invoke the binary directly. That's because apachectl is a script that previously loads the envvars file before invoking the httpd binary.

So, if you fancy to run apache2 directly at least do this first to load the envvars file in your environment (make sure envvars is there first in your system or check the contents of apachectl to locate where it is):

```
. /etc/apache2/envvars
```

Comment: Ok, let me clarify this for my little mind. I should be starting my server with `service apachectl start` instead of `service apache2 start` is that it?

Comment: Ok, I now start my server with `apache2ctl start` but the server shut down again during the night...

Comment: @Sharcoux you are mixing issues. If it shuts down you have something programmed that stops it. Or check the OS logs for cron entries

Comment: What I mean is that apache is down, but I wonder if the server is not crashing and restarting, but I don't know how I can figure that out... I have nothing in the cron entries that would do that

Comment: Ok, I finally discovered that I could know by typing `uptime`. It is up for 4 days, so it didn't crash during the night

Comment: So, really, something seems to be asking apache to shut down. Is there a place where I could log the program that is asking apache to shutdown ?

Comment: I may have an idea: is it possible that apache shuts down when an update occur in my mysql database ?

Comment: ok, maybe it looks more like this actually https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/apache-down-every-week-caught-sigterm.6344/